# Urban Fantasy book with a college student who inherits a book of rituals from his grandmother, and uses modern science to improve summoning a demon

Tags: story-identification, novel, urban-fantasy

I could have sworn I found this book via this site (from someone else identifying it as an answer), but my searches have been futile. The main character is a college student, I think in the United States. He's close to his grandmother, who lives in some sort of assisted care facility. Shortly after she dies (I think it may have been from natural causes), the section of the facility where she lived catches fire, and the protagonist receives her legacy to him, a grimoire of spells, including demon summoning, and I think the staff she uses to cast magic (I remember it being stated to be made from dark wood, and I think he'd assumed it was her cane). I don't recall if the package was mailed to him, or if it was discovered in the ashes of the facility. One of the spells in the grimoire is to summon a demon, and he does so, but only after using his chemical experience to provide more "pure" ritual elements (I think I remember him using sodium vapor lamps instead of candles, and him locating pure chemicals for use in inscribing his circles rather than securing particular types of chalk), which makes his magic unusually powerful, resulting in him safely summoning, and binding, a succubus. I think she explicitly states that either she killed his grandmother, or was trying to capitalize on her death.

I also remember there being an early sexual encounter at a party with a fellow student, female (the sex being described in graphic, but not pornographic, detail) who was described as being unusually callous, or unemotional, and I assumed that that character would be revealed to be the demon in disguise. Now that I type that, I remember another (male) student having shown up dead recently, associated with the one he had sex with, a further indicator of a succubus. I don't think I got far enough into the book to verify this, though.

I don't remember anything about the cover of the book. I think the title had "Demon" in it. I don't remember the length of the book, although I suspect it was a full length novel, not a short story. I read it in the last 2-3 years, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that didn't take long. A search for `site:goodreads.com college student grandmother dies summons demon` turned up *[Birthright](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57904386-birthright)*, which is the first book of the *Demon Hunter* series by Michael Dalton.

> Jimmy Kaplan has a hard enough time staying on top of his graduate studies in Chemical Engineering and dealing with the death of his quirky, cantankerous grandmother, who raised him from childhood.
>
> When a beautiful, mysterious woman appears in his apartment building and friends start turning up dead, Jimmy finds himself drawn into his grandmother’s books on magic and demonology, even as he scorns them as superstition.
>
> But all is not as it seems. For his grandmother was tied up with an ancient legacy that Jimmy must face whether he believes in it or not. And he finds that magic and chemical engineering are not so incompatible . . . especially when it comes to beautiful, voluptuous demons.
>
> Demon Hunter: Birthright is the first novel in the Demon Hunter series and contains explicit adult scenes and themes of harem, black magic and demonology.